# User can not login after registering on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to set up authentication system on Laravel from scratch but I can not make the user to log in after the user its registered.

My RegisterController to store the user:

```
public function store()
{

    $this->validate(request(),[
        'name'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required',
        'password'=>'required'
    ]);

   $user = User::create(request(['name', 'email','password']));

    auth()->login($user);

    return redirect()->home();
}
```

Now everything works great but when i go to login form I cant log in. Here is my SessionsController that deals with login:

```
public function store()
{

if(!auth()->attempt(request(['email','password']))) 

    return back();
}
 return redirect()->home();
}
```

What I am doing wrong here that I can not log in the user?!

Comment: I think because you are already logged in with this `auth()->login($user);` try to logout and then log in !!

Comment: I do have a logout link which destroys the auth() session, but when i try it again to log in doesnt work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case I see that when you register a user you are saving their password as a PLAIN TEXT on database, which is VERY WRONG.

Now the issue happens when `attempt()` is trying to login the user, it is getting the email and password will bcrypt the password to compare with a hashed one on database(your case u are saving as a plain text).

When you create the user `bcrypt`() the password like so:

```
public function store()
    {

        $this->validate(request(),[
            'name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required'
        ]);


       $user = User::create([ 
            'name' => request('name'),
            'email' => request('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt(request('password'))
            ]);


        auth()->login($user);

        return redirect()->home();
    }
```